# Semicontinuity of the product of two functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization

Let $f(x)$ be a left continuous and non-increasing real-valued function. Can I prove that $f(x)x$ is upper semicontinuous?

Comment: obvious: the product of two semicontinuous functions is semicontinuous and $f(x)$ decreasing and left-continuous is semicontinuous

Comment: What do you mean "semicontinuous".... typically we talk about semicontinuous at a point.  Like in this picture: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Upper_semi.svg

Comment: @Squirtle: ...And a function that is semicontinuous at every point of its domain of definition is simply said to be "semicontinuous".

Answer (score 1):

This is not only [obvious](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650184/semicontinuity-of-the-product-of-two-functions#comment1369474_650184), it's also false. Let 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 1,\quad &x\le -1;\\ 0, & x>0\end{cases}$$
The product $g(x)=xf(x)$ is not upper semicontinuous at $-1$, because 
$$g(-1)=-1 < \limsup_{x\to -1}g(x)=0$$

Answer (score 1):

According to proposition 2 on page 362 of Bourbaki's ["General Topology: Chapters 1–4"](https://books.google.com/books?id=SBdtCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA362), the product of two *positive* upper-semicontinuous functions is upper-semicontinuous. It follows that the answer two your question depends on the domain of definition of your function:

- if it is contained in $[0, \infty)$, then $xf$ is upper-semicontinuous;
- if it contains negative numbers, the answer given by **@you can call me AI** shows that $xf$ may fail to be upper-semicontinuous.